# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on this c code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


void createProcess(pid_t p, char* args[])
{
    p = fork();
    if (p == 0)
    {
        execvp("./u", args);
    }
}

void swap(float lat[], float lng[], float mag[], int j)
{
    float temp;
    
    temp = lat[j];
    lat[j] = lat[j+1];
    lat[j+1] = temp;

    temp = lng[j];
    lng[j] = lng[j+1];
    lng[j+1] = temp;

    temp = mag[j];
    mag[j] = mag[j+1];
    mag[j+1] = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(float lat[], float lng[], float mag[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (lat[j] > lat[j+1])
            {
                swap(lat, lng, mag, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t t;
    char s[256];
    int i, j, status;
    pid_t p, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, wpid;
    int MAX_PROCESSES = 10;
    char* files[MAX_PROCESSES];
    status = 0;

    time_t a = time(NULL);

    /* ============================================== */
    // INSERTING INFORMATION INTO ARRAYS

    char *fileName = "earthquake_30days.txt";
    char line[256];
    int fileSize = -1;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        fileSize++;
    }
    
    
    printf("The total number of entries in %s is %d\n", fileName, fileSize);

    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    float latitude[fileSize];
    float longitude[fileSize];
    float magnitude[fileSize];
    
    char *token;
    
    i = -1;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        if (i != -1)
        {
            token = strtok(line, ",");
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            latitude[i] = atof(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            longitude[i] = atof(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            magnitude[i] = atof(token);
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    // Inserting info into file

    int processes;
    printf("\nEnter number of concurrent processes: ");
    scanf("%d", &processes);
    printf("\n");
    
    if (processes > MAX_PROCESSES)
    {
        printf("That is too much.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    clock_t begin;

    if (processes != 1)
    {
        int pieceSize = fileSize/processes;
        char* files[processes];
        int first, last;
        first = 0;
        last = pieceSize;

        for (i = 0; i < processes; i++)
        {
            strcpy(line, "piece");
            sprintf(s, "%d", i);
            strcat(line, s);
            strcat(line, ".txt");
            fileName = line;
            files[i] = fileName;

            fp = fopen(fileName, "w");

            // INSERTING INFORMATION TO FILES
            for (j = first; j < last; j++) {
                // CREATING INFORMATION
                sprintf(s, "%f", latitude[j]);
                strcpy(line, s);
                strcat(line, ",");
                sprintf(s, "%f", longitude[j]);
                strcat(line, s);
                strcat(line, ",");
                sprintf(s, "%f", magnitude[j]);
                strcat(line, s);
                fprintf(fp, "%s\n", line);
            }
            fclose(fp);
            first += pieceSize;
            if (i == processes - 2) {
                last += pieceSize;
                j = fileSize - last;
                last += j;
            } else {
                last += pieceSize;
            }
        }
    
        
        char* args[MAX_PROCESSES] = {{"piece0.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece1.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece2.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece3.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece4.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece5.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece6.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece7.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece8.txt", NULL},
                        {"piece9.txt", NULL}};

        createProcess(p, args[0]);
        createProcess(p2, args[1]);
        
        if (processes >= 3){
            createProcess(p3, args[2]);
        }
        if (processes >= 4){
            createProcess(p4, args[3]);
        }
        if (processes >= 5){
            createProcess(p5, args[4]);
        }
        if (processes >= 6){
            createProcess(p6, args[5]);
        }
        if (processes >= 7){
            createProcess(p7, args[6]);
        }
        if (processes >= 8){
            createProcess(p8, args[7]);
        }
        if (processes >= 9){
            createProcess(p9, args[8]);
        }
        if (processes >= 10){
            createProcess(p10, args[9]);
        }

        while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
    } else {
        begin = clock();

        // Sorting from arrays

        bubbleSort(latitude, longitude, magnitude, fileSize);

        clock_t end = clock();

        double total_time = (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Total time to sort %s was %0.3fs\n", fileName, total_time);
    }

    time_t b = time(NULL);

    printf("\nTotal time of program was %lds\n", (b-a));

    exit(0);
}
```

Why am I getting the "Segmentation fault: 11" error on this code? Is it because of MAX_PROCESSES not being initialized?

I am also getting the "variable-sized object may not be initialized" error for the line
"char* args[MAX_PROCESSES] = {{"piece0.txt", NULL},"

I don't know where my code is wrong so if someone could look at it and point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: You have two `files` arrays: `files[MAX_PROCESSES]` and `files[processes]`. You never use the first array. You assign to the second array, but never use it for anything.

Comment: why do you have all those `sprintf()` and `strcat()` calls? Just use `fprintf(fp, "%f,%f,%f\n", latitude[j], longitude[j], magnitude[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

`char *args[MAX_PROCESSES]` means an array of strings. But you're initializing it with a 2-dimensional array of strings. So it should be:

```
char* args[2][] = {
    {"piece0.txt", NULL},
    {"piece1.txt", NULL},
    {"piece2.txt", NULL},
    {"piece3.txt", NULL},
    {"piece4.txt", NULL},
    {"piece5.txt", NULL},
    {"piece6.txt", NULL},
    {"piece7.txt", NULL},
    {"piece8.txt", NULL},
    {"piece9.txt", NULL}
};
```

Comment: Still getting the error " 171:14: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
                char* args[2][MAX_PROCESSES] = { "

Comment: Make MAX_PROCESSES a macro instead of a variable. Or just use `[]`